# Stop Retry in WSO2 ESB loadbalance endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have created a service in which I have to stop retry if first endpoint is down. I have also used failover false in loadbalance but still it is retrying.

**Start StopRetryServiceProxy**

```
<syn:endpoint name="StopRetryServiceProxy_EPR">
<syn:loadbalance policy="roundRobin" failover="false">
    <syn:endpoint name="PStopRetryService-P116_64080">
        <syn:address uri="http://XXX_01:64080/axis2/services/XXX">
            <syn:timeout>
                <syn:duration>30000</syn:duration>
                <syn:responseAction>fault</syn:responseAction>
            </syn:timeout>
            <syn:markForSuspension>
                <syn:errorCodes>101504, 101505</syn:errorCodes>
                <syn:retriesBeforeSuspension>0</syn:retriesBeforeSuspension>
                <syn:retryDelay>1</syn:retryDelay>
            </syn:markForSuspension>
            <syn:suspendOnFailure>
                <syn:errorCodes>101500, 101501, 101506, 101507, 101508</syn:errorCodes>
                <syn:initialDuration>30000</syn:initialDuration>
                <syn:progressionFactor>1.0</syn:progressionFactor>
            </syn:suspendOnFailure>
        </syn:address>
    </syn:endpoint>
    <syn:endpoint name="StopRetryService-P117_64080">
        <syn:address uri="http://XXX_02:64080/axis2/services/XXX">
            <syn:timeout>
                <syn:duration>30000</syn:duration>
                <syn:responseAction>fault</syn:responseAction>
            </syn:timeout>
            <syn:markForSuspension>
                <syn:errorCodes>101504, 101505</syn:errorCodes>
                <syn:retriesBeforeSuspension>0</syn:retriesBeforeSuspension>
                <syn:retryDelay>1</syn:retryDelay>
            </syn:markForSuspension>
            <syn:suspendOnFailure>
                <syn:errorCodes>101500, 101501, 101506, 101507, 101508</syn:errorCodes>
                <syn:initialDuration>30000</syn:initialDuration>
                <syn:progressionFactor>1.0</syn:progressionFactor>
            </syn:suspendOnFailure>
        </syn:address>
    </syn:endpoint>
</syn:loadbalance>
```

Can anyone please help me out? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem with WSO2 ESB 4.9.0. Finally I found a solution with dynamic endpoints. You can write the XML directly in the registry and put the failover="false" in the XML. What you have to be aware is to not modify the endpoint from the Endpoints view, because the attribute "failover" is not maintained in it